# Is it efficient to return Promise from background process to renderer process?

Tags: node.js, electron

I came to realize that `remote` module is harmful to performance because of the cascading messages back and forth between main and renderer process. So I eliminated all `remote` module usage in my code and utilized pure `ipcRenderer` module to pass arguments to main process and get processed data back. My question is if the main process return a `promise` (eg: database read promise), would that still be efficient or I should resolve that promise in main process, then return data to renderer process ?

Comment:  why you want to pass your data from point a(server) to point b(wotker) to pass it to point c(ui). If you can easily pass it from a to c, promises by default runs on the background if whatever you get from the server requires some heavy calcs or something that will keep the main thread busy for quite some time, the yes us a worker while the worker resolves the whatever your ui is free to listen to the user

Comment: Passing js objects/instances from process a to proccess b is afaik not possible, since they are two completle indepndet V8 instances.